# Genymotion + Targeting Tablet layouts issues with scrolling with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, genymotion

SO, I'm working on an app that has this hierarchy for a particular detail fragment:

```
CoordinatorLayout
    AppBarLayout 
        CollapsingToolbarLayout 
            Toolbar 
    NestedScrollView
```

This is the setup:

- CollapsingToolbarLayout has **scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"**
- The Toolbar having a **layout_collapseMode="pin"**
- NestedScrollView has **layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"**

So when the NestedScrollView is scrolled by the user, the ToolbarLayout will shrink until entirely collapsed, but the Toolbar will only shrink as far as the minimum height it is sent to since it is set to pin when collapsed. This is a fairly common UI/UX pattern I believe. It is just a simple Master-Detail format.

With that being said, on phones my app should show the master fragment followed by the detail fragment when interacted with. On tablets/phablets the both master and detail fragments are to be shown side-by-side such that the detail fragment changes upon user interaction in the main fragment. This is done by having different structured layouts within the layout-sw600dp folder I created.

### The problem

The setup works great on a physical phone, but when I test the app on a Genymotion emulator for tablets/phones there is a problem. Using the layout-sw600dp folder I appropriately show the two fragment side-by-side, but the scrolling behavior no longer functions as expected. The detail fragment's NestedScrollView will scroll but the CollapsingToolbarLayout no longer shrinks, likewise the toolbar doesn't shrink and pin in-place either. The whole CollapsingToolbarLayout just sticks in place and the NestedScrollView won't scroll to show the entire bottom contents. Can someone explain why I am seeing this behavior? The API level shouldn't be the issue, so I'm lost. I tested the two pane setup on my physical phone running Android 5.1 and the scrolling behavior works just as expected (but the content very compressed as expected as well!)

Another, problem is that when I run this on the Genymotion phone emulators, it will show the two pane setup with the fragments side-by-side even though it shouldn't... The width/height of the phones for 4.1+ emulators are at minimum 768 x 1280 so the layout-sw600dp resources are used..

This has been tested on: Android 4.4/5.1 Tablets with sizes 2560x1600 and Android 4.4/5.1 phones all on the Genymotion emulator

Comment: which version of appcompat are you using ?

Comment: 23.1.0 with buildTools of 23.0.1 targeting SDK 23

Comment: For showing fragments side by side, are you adding another layout (like LinearLayout or something ?) in between ? because for `CoordinatorLayout` to work automatically, scroll should be a direct descendant and not get nested.

Comment: Yes I am making the NestedScrollView a direct descendent of the CoordinatorLayout. Like I said this ONLY occurs on Genymotion emulators. On my physical device for both phone and tablet this error is not reproduced.

Comment: Any solution to this? No appbars collapse on Genymotion for me